# Is there a way to map the unit interval to a beta distribution?

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, linear-transformations

I'm currently attempting to figure out if there's a way to map numbers distributed on the unit interval to a beta distribution (for instance, the Beta(1/2, 1/2) or any other beta distribution).  For context, the first step of my problem involves mapping the real line to the unit interval (I'm currently working with the (Sin(x) + 1) / 2 transformation).

Is this possible?  Any ideas on how to approach this problem would be much appreciated!

Comment: There's always https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inverse_transform_sampling If you have the inverse cumulative of the beta distribution (as you would in R or Matlab)

Comment: Here's a quick script (in Matlab/Octave): us = rand(10000,1); betas = betainv(us, 0.5, 0.5); hist(betas,50);